# Firefox randomly disables keyboard input

Tags: firefox, keyboard

Firefox (Windows 7) will randomly disable keyboard input system wide. I have found that opening a new tab and loading a random page like google (by clicking a bookmark) can sometimes fix it.

It happens many times throughout the day. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: do You use addons/plugins?

Comment: Yes, just pretty ordinary ones: Adblock Plus, Webmail Adblocker, video download helper, and one that's added by kaspersky.

Comment: Can You disable them for testing? One of them might cause some compatibility issue. The best way to find out is to disable all and see if the problem appears again.

Comment: I'll try that, but because it's a seemingly random occurrence it will take some time to see if it has changed anything.

Comment: Assuming it is not a virus, You can only find most of these kind of problems by testing. Another choice You have is to contact Mozilla support https://support.mozilla.org/

Comment: Does the problem happen while You are watching a video? When the keyboard is disabled, none of the keys work, (like the Win key, or ctrl + alt + del)?

Comment: Video doesn't cause it. I'm not sure about the keys, I'll try testing that when it happens again.

Comment: @Divin3 I have been using safe mode and it has not happened so I think it's pretty safe to say it must be a plugin causing the problem. I'm suspicious of the kaspersky one...

Comment: Yes that can be a problem. Now You need to turn off the plugins one by one until You find out which one is causing the problem. Start with kaspersky. The video download helper is also suspicious to me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem as well (but with Windows 10), and I noticed we both have Kaspersky in common.

Disabling the "Kaspersky Protection" add-on resolves the issue for me.